# How to use exemplar hero ability

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I've invested three points into the "Exemplar" ability of my Empire Captain Lupido Huldorf. But I cannot recruit units with the three extra levels. I've tried deploying the hero, but that's just for increasing public order.

Although I've now found that it does affect some of my cavalry...

So how exactly does this skill work?

It says "all recruits"...

Answer (score 2):

"Exemplar" works simply by having the hero in the same province where you are doing the recruiting. Note that any units already on the production stack prior to the hero moving there / gaining the ability does NOT get to benefit from the skill. In most cases you can cancel the recruiting and add the unit back, at which point the bonus will apply, though units that were bought at a discount and/or takes multiple turns to build will have to be restarted. It's up to you if that's worth it.

I can confirm that the hero does NOT need to be part of the Lord doing the recruiting's army, nor does he (as you correctly assumed) need to be deployed.

I cannot confirm if it works on all unit types, but I tried with a few and they all seemed to benefit from the additional experience (ranks and experience seem to be used interchangeably where units are concerned, though they mean different things for heroes and lords). Heroes and Lords are not counted as recruits for the purposes of this skill.

I have no other source than in-game testing at this point, as I couldn't find anything in the game's documentation or manual about the precise rules governing the skill.

I also did not have the correct configuration of heroes to easily test whether multiple instances of the skill stacks or the highest one present takes precedence, but I would assume the latter.

Comment: Weird, I did try this. Of course existing recruitment would not benefit. Maybe I'm confusing rank with experience. Will test when I get my PC back :P and maybe even make another bounty to give you. Had not seen your answer in time.

Comment: Well at first I thought there was a difference between rank and experience too - why else use different terms, right? And maybe there is - but it seems to be the same thing, at least for units.

Answer (score 0):

The feature actually works as expected.
Only from rank 8, the icon is gold instead of brown, missed the difference.
So the recruited units where actually of the correct level.